# 4-inch simulator strange result

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

On right there is simulator and on the left you can see the ViewController in `xcode5`. Problem: black space at the top and bottom of the simulator.Even the Carrier and time not showing at top . Issue in 4-inch screen and in 3.5-inch screen its working perfectly 
[image]

Comment: Have you included the iphone5 launch image `Default-568h@2x.png`? The app will not run in full screen if this is missing.

Comment: did you checked the dimension??

Comment: `"Nope sir"` your missing it or `"Nope sir"` that isn't the issue?

Comment: OK add it and if it works I will add as an answer then.

Comment: @Popeye It was working fine yesterday without launch imge

Comment: It shouldn't have been, are you sure there wasn't a blank launch image that has since been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of your question, you are missing the `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image, for your app to utilities the whole iPhone 5 screen you need to include this launch image otherwise it will not launch in full screen.

[Here is a link to the Apple documentation for Human User Interface for launch images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

Answer (score 3):

add a `Default-568h@2x.png` image to your project and problem will be gone.